# Linux ALSA intel_hda_snd on Celeron J4115

Tags: linux, audio, debian, alsa

first of all thank you for the attention. I already uploaded info about my cconfiguration in the following link http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=10a60835f6027cf2e6eb06a319895739f2cccd34

The PC is a laptop, brand KUU model xbook, cpu Intel Celeron J4115, linux distribution is Kali, kernel is 5.10. (I have same issues with other distributions.

The issue is not related to pulseaudio but to ALSA as it does not show the integrated stereo output but just HDMI(and i have only 1 external HDMI).

I tried to pass grub "915.disable_power_well=0" added model=auto as option to snd_hda_intel in modprobe. Checking the information in the model list of hda i can't find the exact occurrence of my card. This should be the windows driver page https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c9DHiS8DEp3HSOzAvJ71bBrW-tgzyJsf (link from http://kuu-tech.com/page2.html). I'm open to any possible test/try.